# Full documentation on Scala's XML support?

Tags: xml, scala, scala-2.8

I'm reading the preprint of the 2nd Ed of Programming in Scala, but as it says it "only scratched the surface of what you can do with XML".  Are there any resources for understanding the entire XML support in Scala 2.8? (right now, I want to know about namespace handling, but I'd like to have something complete to refer to).

Scaladoc doesn't count.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a book by the author of the Scala XML supoort. Scala XML support did not change much over the versions so it is still up to date: http://burak.emir.googlepages.com/scalaxbook.docbk.html

This is a very good article: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/working-with-scalas-xml-support

There's also a nice article here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-scalaxml/

Comment: The good old scala xml book can be found here: https://burakemir.ch/scalaxbook.docbk.html